# Comparing an int value to an array, then display if value matches or does not match

Tags: c#

I am brand new to programming and was interested in C#. I am studying arrays and have to compare my variable (checkNum) to my array(myNums[10]). I read posts here and several other sites and saw how to compare but getting stuck on how to properly display the comparison as shown in my attempt with the if/else statement below:(I will continue to research, but would appreciate and nudges in the right direction. Not necessarily the answer as I am wanting to learn) :)

Here is my code:

```
int[] myNums = new int[10];
int checkNum;
Console.WriteLine("Enter 10 numbers:");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Number {0}: ", i + 1);
    myNums[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("You entered:");
foreach (int x in myNums)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", x);
}
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Enter another number:");
checkNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
bool exists = myNums.Contains(checkNum);

if (checkNum == myNums[10])
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} is in the Array.", checkNum);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Your number {0} does not match any number in the Array.",
        checkNum);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: In addition to all the answers regardin array boundaries and not using exists var I would add that it's usually a good idea to use int.TryParse(string, out int) to avoid bad input.

Comment: +1 for asking for help instead of asking for the answer

Answer (score 6):

```
bool exists = myNums.Contains( checkNum );
if( checkNum == myNums[10] )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Your number {0} is in the Array.", checkNum );
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Your number {0} does not match any number in the Array.", checkNum );
}
```

Should be

```
bool exists = myNums.Contains( checkNum );
// or simply if(myNums.Contains(checkNum)) as you don't use the variable again
if( exists )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Your number {0} is in the Array.", checkNum );
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Your number {0} does not match any number in the Array.", checkNum );
}
```

You perform the check correctly, but you don't use the result (`exists`) and simply (attempt to) compare the new number to the last element in the array.  Of course, at this point your program just crashes because you have overrun the bounds of your array.

Arrays are 0 indexed, i.e., `nums[10]` contains indices 0-9.

Comment: `Contains` would make a bunch of my code a lot simpler. :) ++

Comment: Thank you. I see where I made that mistake now using the other variables for the "if" statement vice the bool "exists" which is performing the comparison. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the array to see if the value is in it:

```
bool exists = false;
for (int i=0; i<myNums.Length; i++)
{
    if (checkNum == myNums[i])
    {
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (exists)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} is in the Array.", checkNum);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Your number {0} does not match any number in the Array.",
        checkNum);
}
```

Comment: `Contains()` is far more simple to use.

Comment: Contains is simpler, but you can do a greater result iterating, so you can see which index is equal, and which is not.

Comment: Well then you would use `IndexOf` and check for `-1`, still no need for a loop in your code.  The OP doesn't need to know the index anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the last if statement checking for:  `checkNum == myNums[10]`? It should use the `exists` variable.